# ListView problem "cannot resolve constructor arrayadapter anonymous"

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, listview, anonymous

I got error on this line:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allOnDay);
```

The Error is:

> cannot resolve constructor arrayadapter anonymous...

I have this code in the `onCreate`:

```
ArrayList<String> allOnDay = new ArrayList<>();
cal_ListView = findViewById(R.id.cal_ListView);
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
   if (values.get(i).equals(year+"")) {
      if (keys.get(i).getMonth()== month +1 && keys.get(i).getDay() == dayOfMonth) {
         allOnDay.add(data.get(i));
      }
   }
}
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allOnDay);
cal_ListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Any Suggestions how I can correct this?

Comment: From where you call this?

Comment: please include more of the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you try to initialize `ArrayAdapter` other than Activity `context`. In that case use `getApplicationContext() or getContext() or getActivity()` instead of `this`.

Use

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allOnDay);
```

Instead of

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allOnDay);
```